# Read all result one by one

Tags: java, string, swing, jdbc, jtextfield

i write this code for next button. When i click i get only first row from table. Help me how i get the all rows one by one?

```
   public void next(){
      try{
          String Url = "Jdbc:Odbc:DirDSN";
          Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Url,"sa","mysql");
          //        Statement st = con.createStatement();
          String sql = "SELECT * FROM PersonInformation";
          PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql,
               ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
          ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
          if(rs.next()) {
              String name = rs.getString("First_Name");
              String lName = rs.getString("Last_Name");
              String add = rs.getString ("Address");
              String em = rs.getString("Email_Id");
              String cell = rs.getString("cell#");
              //        System.out.println("name"+ name+ "lastName"+lName);
              //        set();
              jTextField2.setText(name);
              jTextField3.setText(lName);
              jTextField4.setText(add);
              jTextField5.setText(em);
              jTextField10.setText(cell);
          } else {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"no next record available");
          }
       } catch(Exception sqlEx) {
            System.out.println(sqlEx);
       }
   }
```

Please tell me how i get the data from table created in data base in the form of one by one row. i write this code for next button, but i get only first record of table by clicking next button, i want if i click the next button ,it should show all record one by one in the gui.guide me plz

Comment: Keep calling `rs.next()` to get the next record until you run out.

Comment: while (rs.next ()) {}

Comment: down_votes are probably for crazy mess that you posted here (meaning your original code), isn't (now) this question nicer ....

Comment: Connection, PreparedStatement and ResultSet should be close() in finally(try - catch - finally) block otherwise stays (increasing) in JVM used memory

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.

1. Change the loop from `if` to `while`
2. You are populating `JTextField` when the loops end you will see only last values because other is over write. change it into `System.out.println();` and adjust your GUI accordingly

Comment: i am new in java , please if u provide me little bit piece of code for this, i will be very grateful

Comment: what you want to do actually? if you want to populate all result try using JTable here same sample http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/HCI/HCI_Handout_CALLER/node167.html

Comment: i want simply to display the table records of my database into my application Gui one by one by clicking the next button.